# RSS feed tailored for a newly subscribed user

Tags: rss, feeds

If I want to support a RSS feed that will allow users to have articles from the very beginning of time and gets updates at a specified interval, is there already a script / program that will let me do this? The platform, language, or implementations are not important. I just want to know if there is something like this on the web.